# How to determine different behaviors with 2 booleans?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have 2 `boolean` variables, for example:

```
boolean isWhite;
boolean isTall;
```

So I want to determine a different behavior for the 4 possible cases (`{(isWhite, isTall), (!isWhite, isTall), (isWhite, !isTall), (!isWhite, !isTall)}`).

1) Is there a **more elegant and practical way to do it** than with using `if/else` each time?

```
if(isWhite) {
    if(isTall) {
        // Case 1
    }
    else {
        // Case 2
}
else {
    if(isTall) {
        // Case 3
    }
    else {
        // Case 4
}
```

2) Would it be of **any difference doing something like this instead?**

```
if (isWhite && isTall)
    // Case 1
if (isWhite && !isTall)
    // Case 2
if (!isWhite && isTall)
    // Case 3
if (!isWhite && !isTall)
    // Case 4
```

Comment: Hint: consider `if(isWhite && isTall)`. If this test is `false` you know that either 1) `isWhite == false`, 2) `isTall == false` or 3) both are `false`. So all you  then need to test is `!isWhite`, `!isTall` and `!isWhite && !isTall`. Further such deductions are possible; but might add to complexity.

Comment: If the behaviors are completely different I'd prefer #2 as deeper indentations seem to be more difficult to read. You can also google on case classes / pattern matching in Scala to see another option available there

Comment: if you gonna do this way , better use `else-if`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second solution is more readable. But you should use if-else instead of just if-statements. Consider if the first case is already true. The other 3 if statements still will be computed. If you use if-else statements and the first case is true, the other 3 statements will be just skipped.

```
if (isWhite && isTall) {//case1}
else if (isWhite && !isTall) {//case2}
else if (!isWhite && isTall) {//case3}
else {//case4}
```

Comment: The last `!isWhite` is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer the first if/else arrangement unless you can use an `enum` Say your booleans were `a` and `b`

```
enum Combination { 
   A_B, NA_B, A_NB, NA_NB;
}
```

where NA_NB is not A, not B.

```
switch(comb) {
   case A_B:
         //
         break;
   // more cases
   case NA_NB:
         //
         break;
}
```

This scales a bit better when you have more boolean and it can also make combinations which are impossible clearer.

This lends itself to removing the if/else block entirely.

```
enum Combination implements Actionable { 
   A_B {
      public void action(Arg arg) {
          // something
      }
  },
  NA_B {
      public void action(Arg arg) {
          // something
      }
  },
  A_NB {
      public void action(Arg arg) {
          // something
      }
  },
  NA_NB {
      public void action(Arg arg) {
          // something
      }
  };
}
```

Now instead of an if/else or switch you can just call

```
actionable.action(something);
```

You can also easily add combinations, possibly custom `Actionable` which were not part of the original library.

Comment: I really like Java, but it's one of its most annoying aspect. You want to avoid writing 8 lines of `if/else` statements, so you end up writing 30 lines of boilerplate code.

Comment: Also, how would you initialize your Combination? It must come from somewhere, so you'll probably still need some boolean logic to decide if you use `NA_NB` or `A_B`

Comment: @EricDuminil it depends on how complex your situation is. When you start with a couple of flags you can find alter that you want some options to refactor it to add some structure.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternatve would be to convert them into `int`s (i.e. 0 and 1) and use `switch` statement to identify all the scenarios, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    boolean white = true, tall = false;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(white ? 1 : 0);
    result.append(tall ? 1 : 0);


    switch(result.toString()){
        case "00":
            //do something
            break;

        case "01":
            //do something
            break;

        case "10":
            //do something
            break;

        case "11":
            //do something
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: or you could do `switch((white?10:0)+(tail?1:0))` and save creating any objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility is to calculate your caseNumber directly from the booleans :

```
int caseNumber = 1 + (isWhite ? 0 : 2) + (isTall ? 0 : 1);
```

Here's an [example](http://ideone.com/4uayBJ) :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(getCaseNumber(true,true));
        System.out.println(getCaseNumber(true,false));
        System.out.println(getCaseNumber(false,true));
        System.out.println(getCaseNumber(false,false));
        switch(getCaseNumber(true,false)){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Case 1!");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Case 2!");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Case 3!");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Case 4!");
                break;              
        }
    }

    private static int getCaseNumber(boolean bool1, boolean bool2)
    {
        return 1 + (bool1 ? 0 : 2) + (bool2 ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

It outputs :

```
1
2
3
4
Case 2!
```

It's easier to iterate over all possibilities, it scales better with n booleans and it's easier to use with a `switch`statement.

`1 +` is just here to match your case definition, in which `(true,true)` is `Case 1`.

You can remove it if you want `caseNumber` between `0` and `2**n-1`.

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of the `1 + `?

Answer (score 0):

This is an often seen pattern where properties define different cases, by some business logic (founded in the real world).

That kind of control flow is hard to test, to verify, to track bugs from.

The best way is to make it more or less a declarative list.
Maybe remotely something like:

```
{ false, false, (isWhite, isTall) -> { ... } },
{ false, true, (isWhite, isTall) -> { ... } },
{ true, false, (isWhite, isTall) -> { ... } },
{ true, true, (isWhite, isTall) -> { ... } },
```

(More readable to use enums.)

In this way you can create plugins (XML with cases), log better (handler class name). Especially this declarative list can serve as specification of business logic, readable by the customer. Therefore it would be fine if the picked handler is given a string ID+version that appears to the user in some form. For instance a form-version in a PDF.

It means change of code design. But helped me for instance in the case of many similar reports.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Similar to the previous answers, but I use `else if` to shorten my code when handling the two instances in which the booleans don't have the same value.

```
if(isWhite && isTall){/**case 1*/}
else if(isWhite){/**case 2*/}        // only need one boolean
else if(isTall){/**case 3*/}         // on each of these lines
else{/**case 4*/}
```

Saves you a little typing :)